# Find the Method Moment Estimator of parameter $\theta$

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-theory, expectation, parameter-estimation

Find the MME of parameter $\theta$ in the distribution with the density $f(x,\theta)=(\theta +1)x^{-(\theta+2)}$, for $x>1$ and $\theta >0$.

So far I think I have a basic understanding of the MME process, but I am confused about the the execution.

$E[x] =\int x\ f(x,\theta)\ dx$

$=\int_x^{\infty}\ t (1+\theta) \ t^{-(\theta+2)} \ dt$

$=\int_x^{\infty} (1+\theta) \ t^{-(\theta+1)} \ dt$

$=(\theta+1)\int_x^{\infty}t^{-(\theta+1)}dt=?...?= \dfrac{1+\theta}{\theta}, according \ to \ WolframAlpha $

So I have a few concerns... I am not sure if the bounds on my integral are correct, and even if they are not, I am unsure about how I would calculate $\int t^{-(\theta+1)}dt$.

Am I on the right track?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently covered the method of moments in my stats class too.  You want to calculate $E[X]$; however, there's no need to make it a function of $t$.  I worked through that integral and — presumably this is where your ellipsis and question marks came in — I got something different from that Wolfram answer:  The integral evaluated to $(1+\theta)/(\theta x)$.  As it should:  If $x$ is a limit of integration, it doesn't get a specific value that can cancel out somewhere else.

That said, the integral that Wolfram gave you is the one you want; if you calculate

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\cdot f(x)\,dx = \int_{1}^{\infty}(1+\theta)x^{-(1+\theta)}\, dx$$

that's the answer you'll get.  At this point, you're almost finished:  We know that $\mu = E[X] = (1 + \theta)/\theta$, and so because we're using $\mu$ to estimate $\theta$, all we have to do now is write $\theta$ in terms of $\mu$.  The one difference is that, since these are estimates, based presumably on observed data, your answer should be giving $\widehat{\theta}$ in terms of $\bar{x}$.

From here, what answer do you get?

Almost forgot:  As for integrating $t^{-(\theta + 1)}$ or $x$ to the same power:  You're integrating with respect to $x$ (or $t$), so $\theta$ is just a constant.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: thanks for responding! Just to clarify, do you think that the integral should be $\int_1^{\infty} (1= \theta) x^{-(1+\theta)} dx$? That's the thing, I am a bit confused about what the limits should be based on the question. All other similar examples I have seen the parameter $x$ has an upper bound. Moreover, I am not sure if $x$ refers to a random sample $X_1,...,X_n$ 
            $\theta$ is a constant, got it.

Comment: for some reason I am having trouble with the return key, and am unable to make multiple paragraphs in the comment section.

Comment: @k6adams: When you calculate $E[X]$, you evaluate the integral over the entire support of the density function. Since you have the restriction that $x>1$, the support is $(1, \infty)$. Often, you'll see $E[X]$ written generally as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\cdot f(x)\, dx$. This is equivalent, both in the current case and in others, because for any $x$ not in the support, $f(x) = 0$; therefore, those values of $x$ add nothing to $E[X]$.

Comment: If $E[x]=\dfrac{1+\theta}{\theta}$ then, $$E[x]=1+\dfrac{1}{\theta}$$ $$E[x]-1=\dfrac{1}{\theta}$$ $$\hat{\theta}=\dfrac{1}{\bar{x}-1} $$

Comment: @k6adams: The best explanation I've seen for the lowercase/uppercase thing is that $X$, say, is the random variable *before* we've done anything with it; $x$ is a value that the random variable has taken on. So it makes sense that you take the integral of $x$ and not $X$, because you're looking at all the values $X$ takes on. I'm sure there's a lot I'm missing vis-a-vis notation, but keeping this difference in mind has worked for me so far. But anyway, yeah, $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum x_i$, all your observed data points, which means a random sample.

Comment: That's just what I got, $1 / (\bar{x} - 1)$.